# Why does PHP IF conditional remove HTML from OUTPUT?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo

I am trying to create a conditional that echoes something when a custom field is not "empty" (contains something)

The following is what I want to "echo":

```
<div>Who is there?: <?php echo genesis_get_custom_field('FOO'); ?></div>
```

Which properly results in:

A) "Who is there?:"    (when FOO is "empty")

B) "Who is there?: Me"  (when FOO contains "Me")

When I add the following suggested conditional:

```
<?php if ( genesis_custom_field('FOO') != "") { ?>
<div>Who is there?: <?php echo genesis_get_custom_field('FOO'); ?></div>)
<?php } ?>
```

The result is "NULL" as expected when FOO is "empty"

BUT, when FOO = "Me" the resulting echo is:

"Me"  (all "html" is stripped away including the DIV)

I am sure there is a "simple" syntax problem...  I have scoured the PHP manuals and Google to no avail...

The only vague reference I could find that might work is to "echo" the entire line of HTML.  If this is a good solution can someone be so kind as to share an example of how to modify my working "DIV" with embedded "echo" to code that is an "echo" with embedded "DIV"?

Comment: I'm a bit disorientated and need to ask a question for clarification. So if the `FOO` filed is empty, should there be still the question `Who is there?` or not?

Comment: i guess genesis_custom_field('FOO') is echoing instead of returning value

Comment: Yes @fluty, it appears that "genesis_custom_field('FOO') is echoing instead of returning value"...  When I remove "echo genesis_get_custom_field('FOO'); from the html the contents of FOO still echo

Comment: No @Havelock, I do not want to return the "Who is there" (I want the return to be NULL).

Comment: @fluty is definitely on the right track...  Nothing I do after the conditional is used.  The conditional itself is simple echoing "foo" and then stopping...  No idea why!?

Comment: Yes, now I realised these are two different functions, posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now after I realised they're two different functions, I would suggest replacing

```
if ( genesis_custom_field('FOO') != "")
```

with

```
if ( genesis_get_custom_field('FOO') != "")
```

this function should be returning a value, which you can then compare against `""`

further you could replace

```
echo genesis_get_custom_field('FOO')
```

with

```
genesis_custom_field('FOO')
```

Comment: Awesome catch!  The "functions" (genesis) were essentially "swapped" incorrectly...  The conditional requires the "get" function...  Very impressed!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. It took some time till I noticed they're two different functions :)

Answer (score 0):

May be not directly a solution to your problem, but a different approach - is it necessary to output the HTML part in the condition itself? If the "Who is there?" part is the same in both cases, you could just print the HTML "Who is there?" and after that, you could place the PHP condition. Then, if anything is wrong with the condition, it would be much easier to debug.

BTW I would suspect that there is something wrong with return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code :-

```
<?php

      if ( genesis_custom_field('FOO') != "" && !empty(genesis_custom_field('FOO'))) 
      { 
           echo "<div> Who is there?:". genesis_get_custom_field('FOO')."</div>";
      } 
      else
      {
           echo "<div> Who is there?: Me </div>"
      }

?>
```

Comment: This code throws an error.  I suspect it is the genesis_get_custom_field call syntax...  Still working on it...

Comment: @user1593116 there were some syntax errors, I suggested an edit to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( genesis_custom_field('FOO') != "") 
{
    echo "<div>Who is there?: ".
         genesis_get_custom_field('FOO').
         "</div>";
} 
?>
```

How about echo everything out in php?